# "AnyDo" swipe to delete animation

Tags: ios, xcode, animation

[image: Any do swipe to delete animation]

I am trying to implement the table view cell delete on swipe like it is in the AnyDo app. Any help???

My code:

I am using a gesture recognizer

```
      - (UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)swipeRightRecognizer 
      { 
        if (!_swipeRightRecognizer)  
           {
            _swipeRightRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipeFrom:)];
            _swipeRightRecognizer.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight; 
       }  

        return _swipeRightRecognizer; 
       }
```

Adding gesture to cell:

```
       [cell.contentView addGestureRecognizer:self.leftGestureRecognizer];
```

Handling swipe.

```
       - (void)handleSwipeFrom:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)recognizer indexPath: (NSIndexPath *)index
       { 
       if (recognizer.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft)
       { 
        //Table View deletion code.  + Line to be drawn on cell, move that cell to the bottom of the table with animaiton.
       }
```

}

Comment: That is not what this site is for.  This site is for *specific, answerable* questions.  Not custom-made tutorials.

Comment: I asked how to implement this, i dont need a tutorial.  Any example code is what i need.

Comment: Example code is the same thing.  The problem is all you say is "Help".  You haven't shown any attempt that you have made to solve the problem yourself.

Comment: Borrrden, see my edit. Thats what i tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Colin Eberhardt wrote a great tutorial on [How to Make a Gesture-Driven To-Do List App Like Clear](http://www.raywenderlich.com/21842/how-to-make-a-gesture-driven-to-do-list-app-part-13). Swipe to delete funcionality is also iplemented.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [UISwipeGestureRecognizer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UISwipeGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *gRec = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(yourSelector:)];
[gRec setDirection:(UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight | UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionDown | UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft | UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp)];

[yourCell addGestureRecognizer:gRec];
```

In yourSelector method you can handle the swipe :

```
- (void)yourSelector:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"Handle swipe");
    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *gRec = sender;
    UITableViewCell *cell = [gRec view];

    UIImageView *line = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x,y,0,0)];
    [line setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"line.png"]];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animation:^ (void) {
        [cell addSubview:line];
        [line setFrame:CGRectMake(x,y,320,5];
    } completion:nil];
}
```

EDIT :
I added the code for the line, but I'm not able to try it now. However, it should work

Comment: Thanks, I am doing this. How to strike off a row stylishly animate it and put it in the bottom of the table.

Comment: For the "line" you can use an UIImageView which starts with width and height of 0,0 and animates it through [UIView animateWithDuration:animation:completion] and in animation block change the image view frame. To animate and put the cell in the bottom of the table I think you have to subclass your UITableView to create custom animation logic.

Comment: Yeah thanks, the ray wenderlich tutorial was awesome. That is what i exactly want. Any ways thanks a lot.